# Most efficient way to delete first N lines from a log file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have logs enabled for a lot of basic scripts I am running and I need to clear out those logs from time to time.

What is the most efficient way to delete first N lines from a log file in PowerShell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the `Skip` parameter of `Select-Object`

```
Get-Content logfile.log | Select-Object -Skip 10 | Out-File clearedLogfile.txt
```

Comment: This is clearing the whole log file, not just the number of lines mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure? `Get-Content` retrieves the lines to a `System.Array`. The array content is sent down the pipeline to `Select-Object`. `Select-Object` dumps the first 10 entries. The rest is sent down the pipeline to `Out-File`, which writes the lines to the given file.

Comment: I was unaware that using the using the same file in a pipe would clear that file. This was solved by using a variable to hold the value. Thank you.